# change color with ng-style and different conditions

Tags: angularjs

I want to parameter changes of color of my td so I try this and it's working fine:
     {{item.name}}

but when I try to use different conditions for example for

item.name : xxx =>color : red

item.name: yyy =>color : yellow

item.name: aaa =>color : blue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this.

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("ctrl" , function($scope){
  $scope.items = [{"name":"ali"},{"name":"reza"},{"name":"amir"}];
  
  
  $scope.getStyle = function(name){
    if(name == "ali")
      return {'color':'red'};
    if(name == "reza")
      return {'color':'blue'};
    if(name == "amir")
      return {'color':'green'};
    }
  
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <p ng-style ="getStyle(item.name)">{{item.name}}</p>
    </div>
            
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't give you an exact answer as you did not post enough of your code, but see if this helps:

```
<div ng-if="item.name == xxx"><div ng-style="{'background-color': yourColor}"></div>
```

"yourColor" can be either a direct color name like "red" or a scope variable.

You can also use ng-class if your colors are in a class like below:

```
<div ng-class="{'myColor1': item.name == xxx, 'myColor2': item.name == yyy, 'myColor3': item.name == zzz}"></div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can apply classes conditionally:

```
<td ng-class="{red: item.name === 'xxx', yellow: item.name === 'yyy'}">
    {{ item.name }}
</td>
```

then use CSS to set the colors:

```
td.red { background-color: red; }
td.yellow { background-color: yellow; }
```

Comment: thank you for your replay, but I don't want to use css file, I want to parameter colors directly in the ng-class directive.

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.item-color1 {
 background-color: red;
 }
.item-color2 {
 background-color: yellow;
 }

 .item-color3 {
 background-color: blue;
 }
```

in html

```
<td ng-class="{item-color1: item.name == xxx , item-color2: item.name == yyy, item-color3: item.name == aaa}">
```

Comment: thank you for your replay, but I don't want to use css file, I want to parameter colors directly in the ng-class directive.

Answer (score 0):

### ## controllerjs ##

```
 var app = angular.module("app",[]);

    app.controller("ctrl" , function($scope){
  $scope.Unresolved = [{"status":"Assigned"},{"status":"Unassigned"},{"status":"CustomerWait"}];
  $scope.getStyle = function(status){
    console.log('color============>>>>>>>>>',status);
      if(status == "Unassigned")
        return {'background-color':'#d9534f'};
      if(status == "Assigned")
        return {'background-color':'#337ab7'};
      if(status == "CustomerWait")
        return {'background-color':'green'};
   });

       })
```

### jade

```
script(src='js/angularjs/angular.js')(you using version)
tr(ng-repeat='unresolved in unresolveds track by $index')
  td
    select.colorSel(ng-model='unresolved.status',ng-style='getStyle(unresolved.status)')
      option(value='Assigned',) Assigned
      option(value='Unassigned') Unassigned
      option(value='Customer wait') Customer wait
```

Comment: Hi. Please add some details and explanation along with the code posted so it can help others to understand